# Ubuntu loading error terminal gives root access?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

Sometimes when I get an error while starting ubuntu (for example yesterday I got `VCE init error (-110)`), I see a no-desktop terminal, since the whole system is not started correctly. And the terminal is run under **root** user! Does it mean that any user of my computer that faces that kind of errors is going to have a root access to my computer and will be able to run some kind of `rm -rf /`? In case of normal loading I get an access to root only if I am in sudoers group and only after providing my password, so why in case of errors users should have root privileges?

Comment: If this really gives root shell, you probably might wanna report it as a security vulnerability/bug. https://bugzilla.kernel.org

Comment: …better to report it [on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/) so they can figure out whether this is a bug in Ubuntu or from upstream (Debian or kernel.org).

Answer (score 2):

If Ubuntu is so screwed up that it cannot even get the system to run, it drops to a `root` terminal, to give a knowledgeable person a chance to diagnose, repair, recover, ...

The system to which the passerby has `root` access is a severely broken system.

Trying to perform any of the diagnose, repair, recover steps as user `fred` would be impossible. You couldn't even count on `sudo` working for `fred`.